# Sort array in Swift using a variable property?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an NSTableView with an array datasource that I'm sorting when the user clicks on a column header. At the moment I have some IF statements to sort ascending/descending for every column name. Is it possible to perform a sort using a variable property name? That is, instead of hard coding .name in the following example, I could use a variable containing the name of the property instead of .name?

```
tableContents.sort {
    $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

This does work, but I have to duplicate this for every column in the table

Comment: consider to use an NSArrayController to get the sorting stuff for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the properties that are used for sorting have the same type, you could use the built-in key-value access. Consider the following class `A` with two properties `a` and `b` both of which are strings.

```
class A: NSObject, Printable {
    var a: String
    var b: String

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "{ a: \(self.a), b: \(self.b) }"
    }
}
```

Let's say your table contents are build from instances of this class.

```
var tableContents = [A(a: "1", b: "2"), A(a: "2", b: "1")]
```

To sort this array based on the values of either `a` or `b` you could use the following.

```
tableContents.sort {
    let key = "a"
    let oneValue = $0.valueForKey(key) as! String
    let otherValue = $1.valueForKey(key) as! String
    return oneValue.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(otherValue) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

println(tableContents) // [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 1 }]

tableContents.sort {
    let key = "b"
    let oneValue = $0.valueForKey(key) as! String
    let otherValue = $1.valueForKey(key) as! String
    return oneValue.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(otherValue) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

println(tableContents) // [{ a: 2, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }]
```

The only difference in the comparison block is the usage of either `let key = "a"` or `let key = "b"`.

Comment: My properties are not all of the same type, so I take your point. I'm probably asking the impossible. Your solution will probably still come in handy, though. Thanks.